# Login / Register API With Laravel 5

Tags: api, laravel

How do I can create an API with laravel 5, That will be used for login /register for mobile app? Is there any useful tutorial for this type of API.

Like when someone sends a request from a mobile application, I need to authenticate and then send the proper response against that request.

Comment: Simply follow Laravel Auth flow and use the same for RESTful. You can have the guild from Laracasts: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/13. I recommend you to watch them all of the whole series.

Comment: This is not about API,this video just demonstrate how to scaffold Auth in laravel.

Comment: Indeed, after you enable authentication and the login and register page does work, then you have the route for authentication. Use this route for your API request. In fact, that's all the flow. If you want to modify flow, then you can simply override it. The full document is here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication.

Comment: @spicydog I tried that, but I can't figure it out. May you please show us how to do it as json API? I added to my `routes/api.php` - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/340eb025bf7c0f3e4f9397e89b038fba -  and am using `Content-Type` `application/json` and `Accept` `application/json` in headers of requests but am not able to get register, login, logout, forgot password, password reset, working with json API.

Comment: @Noitidart you don't need to put in api.php route file. Just use the web.php one is fine. api.php will have the different middle that can make thing more difficult.
BTW, did you have CSRF into your POST request? When you send POST request to Laravel, you always need to include CSRF token. You can have it in request header or as a form input. Look at the bottom of this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf. There is an example for AJAX.
I will make the whole code for you but it's gonna take some time since there're several files.

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much @spicydog for willing to create whole code tutorial. I am actually a super newbie and would seriously appreciate that. I was able to follow this video - https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/13 - but it didnt get into the ajax. I didn't send the CSRF, I will read that linekd article right away. Thanks very much sir!

Comment: @Noitidart see my answer below. It's a very simple version but should give you the idea on how to make it works.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a very simple version in jQuery format as for example and hosted on GitHub.

Here are all the changes from a fresh Laravel: [See all changed files](https://github.com/spicydog/laravel-ajax-login-example/compare/ebabcf4d09d07499945a4dfaf3f70c27f7dbb079...27b9a1c4b10930a464ad8fb959b33c6fcf8f9c97)

Feel free to adapt to your code.

You can check the step in each commit.

1. **Create the project** (Don't forget to run `php artisan make:auth`)
2. **Make login support AJAX request** (instead of auto redirect) [1a47de4](https://github.com/spicydog/laravel-ajax-login-example/commit/1a47de410baf568a52e8158d46b5214a48f1d4aa)
3. **Login with AJAX** (submit login data via AJAX, Please `CSRF token` header) [80be34d](https://github.com/spicydog/laravel-ajax-login-example/commit/80be34d1d481dca6c79f6f357cd156cbc624605d)
4. **Make register support AJAX** (same as step 2) [89f6dd7](https://github.com/spicydog/laravel-ajax-login-example/commit/89f6dd792e480c2b2f254ac78b2308d2d02ac34d)
5. **Register via AJAX** (Same as step 3) [ab8d2d7](https://github.com/spicydog/laravel-ajax-login-example/commit/ab8d2d7c251d824c73a62c8df9f6cf2339673223)
6. **Use redirect path from Laravel** (Bonus) [27b9a1c4](https://github.com/spicydog/laravel-ajax-login-example/commit/27b9a1c4b10930a464ad8fb959b33c6fcf8f9c97)

By the way, for the mobile app, you may need to use `access token` instead. My example is for web app session. Laravel already have the particular method already just twist a bit.

Comment: Holy heck thanks so much for this detail. I will try this out. I'm making a small hobby project so will try this out on the weekend. It looks super promising. Thank you sir! I think I would follow same as 3 and 5 to support forgot password/reset password correct?

Comment: Your welcome. Happy hacking. :)
Laravel will tell you if there're error from input, you can check the errors and handle in JS. It has its error standard. You can easily wrap it up to the JS framework that you are going to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a login register with laravel you can simply use the Heto Multi auth.. All the required details are there.. 
[Heto Multi Auth](https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth)

Hope This will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Creating a REST Api on Laravel isn’t very difficult. All we need to keep in mind is that where to start and how to prepare RestFull resources. As usual, you can follow this link: [Build Rest Resources With Laravel](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-rest-resources-laravel/)

And if you want that your `API` works with `Mobile Applications` you should use `tymon/jwt-auth` package.
you can find the tutorial to work with `laravel` and `tymon/jwt-auth` in this link: [Create an API Server for Mobile Apps using Laravel](http://blog.nedex.io/create-an-api-server-for-mobile-apps-using-laravel-5-1/)

The `tymon/jwt-auth` contains:

1. Installation of the package.
2. Configuration
3. Creating Tokens
4. Authentication

And the link for `tymon/jwt-auth` package is: 
[tymon/jwt-auth package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)

Answer (score 0):

There is a popular tool named - [Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api) which is specially created for Laravel / Lumen Frameworks and is meant to provide you, a set of tools to help you easily and quickly build your own APIs.

The package provide you with these set of features:

- Content Negotaition
- Authentication
- API Versioning
- Throttling
- Formated / Transformed Responses
- API Blueprint Documentation
- and much more.

You can find the [full documentation of Dingo API here >>](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki)

Comment: I am having an issue with this package,I want to authenticate user from Android App,if user is authenticate then return response vice versa.

Comment: How i can accomplish this ? Do i need to call my auth controller in routes ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that shows how to set up register/login/logout endpoints but he changes it slighlty so we don't get the nice effects of too many login attempts etc. https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial

I am still looking for a tutorial on how to do this, will share when I find.